# Python colormaps in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, python

I would like to reproduce in Tikz examples of [colormaps](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html) in Python. The one which is of interest to me is YlOrRd. I can extract it from the provided pdf but a Tikz solution is better. I've tried three colors (left, middle, right) but this is insufficient.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\definecolor{left}{RGB}{255,255,205}
\definecolor{middle}{RGB}{253,141,60}
\definecolor{right}{RGB}{128,0,38}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rectangle,left color=left,right color=middle,minimum width=2.5cm] (box) at (0,0){};
\node[rectangle,left color=middle,right color=right,minimum width=2.5cm] (box) at (2.5cm,0){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output is below, where the top is the Tikz version of the Python colormap (bottom).

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an approximation using a `hsb` gradient for the first part and using the `red` color in the middle of the second part.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\definecolor{left}{RGB}{255,255,205}
\definecolor{middle}{RGB}{253,141,60}
\definecolor{right}{RGB}{128,0,38}

\colorlet{hsbleft}[hsb]{left}
\colorlet{hsbmiddle}[hsb]{middle}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rectangle,left color=hsbleft,right color=hsbmiddle,minimum width=2.5cm] (box) at (0,0){};
\node[rectangle,left color=middle,right color=right,middle color=red,minimum width=2.5cm] (box) at (2.5cm,0){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For convenience, you may define the new `YlOrRd` shading with all colors (derived from "rainbow spectrum" example of pgfmanual, v3.0.1a, p.1088):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\definecolor{left}{RGB}{255,255,205}
\definecolor{middle}{RGB}{253,141,60}
\definecolor{right}{RGB}{128,0,38}
\colorlet{hsbleft}[hsb]{left}
\colorlet{hsbmiddle}[hsb]{middle}

\pgfdeclareverticalshading{YlOrRd}{100bp}{
  color(0bp)=(hsbleft);
  color(25bp)=(hsbleft);
  color(50bp)=(hsbmiddle);
  color(50bp)=(middle);
  color(67bp)=(red);
  color(75bp)=(right);
  color(100bp)=(right)
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rectangle,shading angle=-90,shading=YlOrRd,minimum width=5cm]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It looks better indeed. What is the `hsb` option for?

Comment: @pluton `hsb` is a color model (provided by `xcolor`). So, the middle color of the first part is computed in this color model.